# How can I decode ajax request's response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, telegram

I'm using Telegram web version. Here is a screenshot of it:

[image]

As you see in the image above, all ajax requests' responses are made of vague characters.  I mean the response contains unknown characters. For example I've received `Text3` as a new comment, but I cannot see it (the word o `Test3`) in the ajax response. I've tested all responses, all of them look the same.

Anyway, do you know how can I decode it? I mean how can I convert them to English characters?

Comment: Can you show your request/response headers?

Comment: @artemisian Why not :-) ..! there you go: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9sES.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cZGP.png). Noted that these headers aren't belong to the image which is in my question.

Comment: Seems the web.telegram website uses a communication protocol that's non-text based. There should be some javascript logic converting those bytes to text so it's displayed nicely on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the response headers for the content encoding or the Content-Type. That may help in figuring out the encoding used by the server.